# Async Serial Port with CancellationToken and ReadTimeout

Tags: c#, asynchronous, serial-port, task, cancellation

I'm trying to wrap the SerialPort's read method in a task that can be awaited, that way I can get the benefits of using a CancellationToken and the timeout from the SerialPort object. My issue is that I cannot seem to get the Task to throw a CancellationException. Here's my code...

```
    static CancellationTokenSource Source = new CancellationTokenSource();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestAsyncWrapperToken();
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to cancel");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
        Source.Cancel();
        Console.WriteLine("Source.Cancel called");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static async void TestAsyncWrapperToken()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var Port = new SerialPort("COM2", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One))
            {
                Port.Open();
                var Buffer = new byte[1];
                await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Starting Read");
                    Port.ReadTimeout = 5000;
                    Port.Read(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length);                        
                }, Source.Token);
            }
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Task Cancelled");
        }
        catch (TimeoutException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Timeout on Port");
        }
        catch (Exception Exc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception encountered {0}", Exc);
        }
    }
```

Is it because the Port.Read method is a blocking call? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Two methods are conceivable.

1. Using ReadAsync
   It is to get the Stream object from the [BaseStream property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.basestream(v=vs.110).aspx) of the SreiaPort object and use the [Stream.ReadAsync Method (Byte[], Int32, Int32, CancellationToken)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193669(v=vs.110).aspx).

   Although it is not exactly matched content, please refer to this.
   [How to cancel Stream.ReadAsync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42305825/how-to-cancel-stream-readasync)
   [NetworkStream.ReadAsync with a cancellation token never cancels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12421989/networkstream-readasync-with-a-cancellation-token-never-cancels)
2. Using [DataReceivedEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived(v=vs.110).aspx) and [SerialDataReceivedEventHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialdatareceivedeventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx)
   Change so that it works with DataReceivedEvent as trigger.
   Please refer to the answer of this article.
   [Sample serial port comms code using Async API in .net 4.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23230375/sample-serial-port-comms-code-using-async-api-in-net-4-5)

p.s.
If you want to work with .NET 4.0 or lower, the following article will be helpful.
It will also be related knowledge to the above.
[If you *must* use .NET System.IO.Ports.SerialPort](http://www.sparxeng.com/blog/software/must-use-net-system-io-ports-serialport)
[Reading line-by-line from a serial port (or other byte-oriented stream)](http://www.sparxeng.com/blog/software/reading-lines-serial-port)

Answer (score 0):

I could only find solutions with exception and closed stream afterwards, so here is my solution as an extension method, which just returns `null` on cancel or timeout:

```
public static async Task<byte[]> ReadBytesAsync(this SerialPort serialPort, 
    CancellationToken cancel, int maxLen = 256, int timeoutInSeconds = 5, byte stop = (byte)'\r')
{
    const int delay = 50;
    int read, i = 0, timeout = timeoutInSeconds * 1000 / delay;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[maxLen];
    while (true) {
        if (serialPort.BytesToRead == 0) {
            await Task.Delay(delay);
            timeout--;
        }
        else {
            i += read = await serialPort.BaseStream.ReadAsync(buffer, i, maxLen - i);
            if (i == maxLen || Array.IndexOf(buffer, stop, i - read, read) >= 0) break;
        }
        if (timeout == 0 || cancel.IsCancellationRequested) return null;
    }
    Array.Resize(ref buffer, i);
    return buffer;
}
```

I had to learn that the `ReadAsync()` implementation doesn't use the `CancellationToken` parameter, and also not the `ReadTimeout` setting, so it would hang forever if no (more) data arrives and could only be cancelled by forcing an error on the stream i.e.
`using (cancel.Register(() => serialPort.DiscardInBuffer())) { }`.

I think the better way is simply not to call it until bytes are received.

Of course my implementation is a bit special, for performance reasons it doesn't read byte by byte, but returns when the stop byte is "somewhere". You should adapt this to your needs.

Bonus: need a string? `serialPort.Encoding.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);`